# Android on finish() recreates Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Strange things happens if I try to finish activity. After calling for the first time activity *finish* method - activity re-creates.

```
BroadcastReceiver requestReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                long resultRequestId = intent.getLongExtra(DVSServiceHelper.EXTRA_REQUEST_ID, 0);

                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "received request id: "+ resultRequestId +", current request id: "+ requestId);

                if (resultRequestId == requestId) {
                    int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(DVSServiceHelper.EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, 0);

                    Logger.debug(TAG, "result code: "+ resultCode);

                    switch(resultCode) {
                        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                            //Dummy intent
                            Intent in = new Intent();

                            Logger.debug(TAG, "HTTP OK");

                            //User logged in successfuly. Finish Login activity
                            LoginActivity.this.setResult(AuthorizationManager.LOGIN_SUCCESS, in);
                            Logger.debug(TAG, "setting result...");
                            LoginActivity.this.finish();
                            Logger.debug(TAG, "finishing...");

                            break;
                            ...
```

Activity onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        Logger.debug(TAG, "[onCreate]");
        ...
```

**LogCat output**

on first attempt:

```
08-14 17:46:00.917: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        result code: 200
08-14 17:46:00.917: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        HTTP OK
08-14 17:46:00.917: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        setting result...
08-14 17:46:00.937: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        finishing...
08-14 17:46:00.977: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        [onCreate]
```

on seconds attempt:

```
08-14 17:50:25.437: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        result code: 200
08-14 17:50:25.437: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        HTTP OK
08-14 17:50:25.437: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        setting result...
08-14 17:50:25.537: D/(7975): [LoginActivity]        finishing...
08-14 17:50:25.567: D/(7975): [MainActivity]         [onActivityResult]
08-14 17:50:25.567: D/(7975): [MainActivity]         [onActivityResult]
08-14 17:50:25.567: D/(7975): [MainActivity]         [onResume]
```

**EDITED**

**MainActivty**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Logger.debug(TAG, "[onActivityResult]");

        if(AuthorizationManager.REQUEST_LOGIN == requestCode) {
            if(AuthorizationManager.LOGIN_FAILED == resultCode) {

                Logger.debug(TAG, "Login failed!");

                Intent login = new Intent(DVSApplication.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(login, AuthorizationManager.REQUEST_LOGIN);
            }
        }
    }



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Logger.debug(TAG, "[onCreate]");

        //if user isn't saved crediantials - show log in activity
        if(!AuthorizationManager.getManager(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()) {

            Logger.debug(TAG, "[onCreate] user is not logged in!");

            Intent login = new Intent(DVSApplication.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(login, AuthorizationManager.REQUEST_LOGIN);
        }
        ...
}

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Logger.debug(TAG, "[onResume]");

        //if user isn't saved crediantials - show log in activity
        if(!AuthorizationManager.getManager(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()) {

            Logger.debug(TAG, "[onResume] User is not logged in!");

            Intent login = new Intent(DVSApplication.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(login, AuthorizationManager.REQUEST_LOGIN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what are you doing in onActivityResult? And is the Activity launched via startActivityForResult?

Comment: after finishing your activity where you expect to go?

Comment: Can you show how you start the LoginActivity?

Comment: are you trying to send result to same activity? is login activity supposed to send any data to other activity in onActivityResult?

Comment: @RvdK yes, *LoginActivity* is launched via *startActivityForResult*. As you can see in logcat output, on first attempt *onActivityResult* is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `startActivityForResult(login, AuthorizationManager.REQUEST_LOGIN);` from the `onresume()` of your main activity. Doing this, you will be able to get back to the main activity. also you should remove it from you `onActivityResult` too if you don't want to go back to the activity after it is finished.

Comment: Is due to that *LoginActivity* was called twice. In *onCreate* and *onResume*?

Comment: yes it's because after finishing that activity, `onresume` of the previous activity is called and again the Login activity gets started in the `onresume` process of the main activity